# Need to configure perl

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, perl, json

I was going to run a perl program and then I got this error message:

```
Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./po2json line 23.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./po2json line 23.
```

I supposse there is some JSON module that needs to get installed perhaps via cpan. Do you have a suggestion for how to enable it?

Thanks

### Update

So I could install the JSON module but now I get another error message

```
Can't locate Locale/PO.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./po2json line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./po2json line 24.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Ubuntu 10.04 this file can be found in the `liblocale-po-perl` package:

```
$ apt-file search Locale/PO.pm
liblocale-po-perl: /usr/share/perl5/Locale/PO.pm
```

Another way to have worked this out:

```
$ apt-cache search Locale::PO
liblocale-po-perl - Locale::PO perl module
```

which you may prefer since `apt-file` is not installed by default.

Answer (score 4):

For `JSON.pm` on ubuntu system, you should install `libjson-perl` package:

```
apt-get install libjson-perl
```

You can find which ubuntu package holds your file thanks to:

```
apt-file search JSON.pm
```